# How can I make a JFreeChart Bar Chart's plot expand to show vertical labels above the bars?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I want to create a Bar Chart, using JFreeChart, with vertical labels above the bars. I can do this using an ItemLabelPositioner as follows:

```
BarRenderer renderer = (BarRenderer)plot.getRenderer();
ItemLabelPosition pOut = new ItemLabelPosition(ItemLabelAnchor.OUTSIDE12, TextAnchor.CENTER_LEFT, TextAnchor.CENTER_LEFT, -Math.PI / 2.0);
renderer.setBasePositiveItemLabelPosition(pOut);
```

However, the labels on the tallest bars go off the top of the chart. Is there a way I can prevent this without doing complicated calculations on label sizes and setting the upper margin?

Answer (score 0):

You may use something like this :

```
renderer.setItemLabelAnchorOffset(10); //giving some margins
```

Comment: I don't think this helps solve my immediate problem, but this is a useful piece of functionality for another issue I have, so thanks!